# Is there an elegant way of finding the average date of an array consisting of moment.js dates?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I use reduce and the dayOfYear function to find the average date of a array of dates.

My current solution works well for dates in the same year. It unfortunately does **not** consider the difference in year between the dates.

```
return moment().dayOfYear(Math.round(items.reduce((a, b) => a + moment(b).dayOfYear(), 0) / items.length)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Could someone guide me in a direction for a similar approach as the above-mentioned code but considering the difference in year between the dates? Any help appreciated.

Comment: As dates are just numbers, why not find the average in number and then transform it into a date?

Comment: @Aviad **That** is **the** solution, that would work.

Comment: @Aviad Yes, I understand the principle and that is exactly what I'm doing in my old solution. My new solution is exactly the same, only difference is that I'm using the full moment.js date instead of just the dayOfYear component.

Answer (score 0):

Since dates are numbers, the correct solution here will be to find the numeric average and then transform it to a date object using Moment (or any other lib)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to just remove the dayOfYear and keep it as a full moment.js date. It now takes the difference between years into consideration.

```
return moment(Math.round(items.reduce((a, b) => a + moment(b), 0) / items.length)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```